# Colab "busy" with red exclamation mark every two hours before the execution is finished

Tags: jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory

Every time, if the execution on colab run for more than two hours, the following things will appear:

On the bottom, it says after the red exclamation mark that "completed", but in fact the task cannot be completed because the estimated finishing time is 8 hours.

On top right it says "busy".

Is it possible to fix this issue? What does the red exclamation mean?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Basically, the notebook is run by connecting to the virtual machine, so if you left your machine idle for a long time it will disconnect. In your case, this is the issue.

=========SOLUTION=========

Step 1. Selecting Runtime

Step 2. Disconnect and delete runtime to return all managed virtual machines assigned to you to their original state.

Step 3. Then click on Reconnect for connection.

This can be helpful in cases where a virtual machine has become unhealthy e.g. due to accidental overwrite of system files, or installation of incompatible software. Colab limits how often this can be done to prevent undue resource consumption. If an attempt fails, please try again later